# Cite page/section/equation number in a footnote associated with a citation

Tags: biblatex, citing, footnotes

How can I cite page, section, and equation numbers in a footnote in LaTeX? The footnote should have the same symbol as the citation. I'm using `bibtex` to generate my bibliography. What I have been doing is using the optional argument to `\cite`, but I find that that can take up too much space in the paragraph.

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) ?

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what you want to achieve. Can you show us what you have so far (we need to know what style you use) and exactly what you want?

Comment: Any news here? Can you give more details about what you want and what you have at the moment (MWE/MWEB)?

Comment: Sorry that I failed to get back to you on this. The answer Micheal Avery provided is helpful, and I'm marking it as best; it doesn't use precisely the format I'd like, but it can be modified in any number of ways. What I originally wanted to do was somewhat ill-thought-out, on reflection; I wanted the footnote to have the same symbol as the citation, but that becomes a problem if there are more than one of the same citation on a page. I was going to write an MWE, but the number of steps required to make something like what I wanted manually was to convince me it was a bad idea to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the optional citation argument in a footnote in an enclosing argument to the same citation.

```
Tax code
\cite[\footnote{\cite[chapter 31, section 4.82.B.IX.3(c).1442(D)]{tax1}}]{tax1}
is dreded by all, but not so much as
\cite[\footnote{\label{tax1label1}\cite[chapter 82, section 12.91.FB.VII.9.382]{tax1}}]{tax1},
but the latter
\cite[\textsuperscript{\ref{tax1label1}}]{tax1}
is not dreded by all.
```

This will end up reading as

```
Tax code [USC17, $^1$] is dreded by all, but not so much as
[USC17, $^2$], but the latter [USC17, $^2$] is not dreded by all.

--- Bilography ---
[USC17] blah blah blah

--- footnotes ---
$^1$ - [USC17, chapter 31, section 4.82.B.IX.3(c).1442(D)]
$^2$ - [USC17, chapter 82, section 12.91.FB.VII.9.382]
```